# Need help calling a Repository from a Controller in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am needing to set up a Unit Test for our project. In our Controllers we are using a Unit of Work which holds all the repositories and calling the repository in our `IHttpActionResult` to get the data.

So far I have set up a Mock of the Interfaces and this is calling the correct `IHttpActionResult` in the Controller but there is no data coming back.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    var repo = new Mock<IAuditReleaseRepository>();
    unitOfWork.Setup(e => e.AuditReleaseRepository).Returns(repo.Object);
    var auditReleaseController = new AuditReleaseController(unitOfWork.Object);
    var result = auditReleaseController.Get() as ViewResult;
    var model = result.ViewData.Model as IQueryable<AuditReleas>;
    Assert.AreEqual(12, model.Count());
}
```

```
public class AuditReleaseController : BaseController
{
    private IAuditReleaseRepository _auditReleaseRepository;
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public AuditReleaseController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this._auditReleaseRepository = unitOfWork.AuditReleaseRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("audit-releases")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var query = this._auditReleaseRepository.GetAll();
        return Ok(query);
    }
}
```

```
public class AuditReleaseRepository : RepositoryBase<AuditReleas>, IAuditReleaseRepository
{
    private readonly RetailAssignmentEntities _entities;

    public AuditReleaseRepository(RetailAssignmentEntities entities) : base(entities)
    {
        this._entities = entities;
    }

    IEnumerable<AuditReleaseDto> IDtoRepository<AuditReleaseDto>.GetAll()
    {
        return base.GetAll().Where(x=>x.IsReleaseEnabled).Select(AuditReleaseMapping.All).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

This is the Mapping that is taking place to get the data in the GetAll method:

```
public class AuditReleaseMapping
    {
        public static Expression<Func<AuditReleas, AuditReleaseDto>> All = (auditRelease) => new AuditReleaseDto()
        {
           EndDate = auditRelease.AuditReleaseEndDate,
           Id = auditRelease.AuditReleaseId,
           Name = auditRelease.AuditReleaseName,
           StartDate = auditRelease.AuditReleaseStartDate,
           AuditPeriodId = auditRelease.AuditPeriod.AuditPeriodId,
           AuditYearId = auditRelease.AuditPeriod.AuditYear.AuditYearId,
           AuditEndDate = auditRelease.AuditPeriod.AuditEndDate,
           AuditStartDate = auditRelease.AuditPeriod.AuditStartDate
        };
    }
```

What would be ideal is to call the Controller, which would call the repository, which would then call the Mapping but so far it's not even calling the Repository to get the data. I need help getting that functionality set up.

Comment: You haven't yet mocked the IAuditReleaseRepository GetAll method

Comment: @andyb952 you want to elaborate on that in an answer?

Comment: Where do you set up the data that you expect the controller to return in your unit test? As mentioned, you should setup `GetAll()` to actually return some data.

Comment: That `GetAll()` is scary - is this code going to load **all** database records in memory before trying to filter them?

Comment: @andyb952 I am needing to return the Mapping entity for my data. Do you have any incite in how to mock the GetAll method to allow that to happen?

Comment: this is far too complicated. unit testing is about functionality. test your repositories, test your business logic. there's no need to go down to controller level. if your model has 12 records then your your view will receive 12 records because you assigned the model to the view. you're now trying to test MVC and check that the model is assigned correctly. the MVC team is doing that test, you don't need to

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to Setup the behavior for your Mock repo.GetAll().  You will need to create a list of AuditReleaseDto's for your Mocked repo to return.  Call it TestAuditReleaseDtos.  You can create this TestData in the beginning of your TestMethod or in the TesstClass initialization.  Then use it in a line right after creating your Mock:

```
    var repo = new Mock<IAuditReleaseRepository>();
    repo.Setup(r => r.GetAll()).Returns(TestAuditReleaseDtos);
    unitOfWork.Setup(e => e.AuditReleaseRepository).Returns(repo.Object);
```